# Images half loading in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am busy working on this website (http://backtohealth.co.za/home.php) but many of the images are not loading in correctly. I have tried pre-loading the images and changing height values but neither worked. This issue only seems to be with the current host as when I tried with another host there were no issues. What could the issue be?

Comment: I get a lot of 403 Forbidden for images in the network log when I check out your site, images do not load at all. Should be a clue as to why you are experiencing this problem.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I will contact the server owner to see what they can do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Chrome Dev Tool (F12), tab `Network`, filter with `Img`, you will see most of picture is loading in the half. So the problem causing by the image's source it self (the server), not causing by the site.

[image]

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll have to contact the server owner to see how this can be resolved.

Comment: In my case this was caused by incorrect `content-length` header in HTTP response. Initially the incorrect size was returned by PHP's `filesize` function. It appears that file size can be cached by PHP engine. That cache can be cleared by using `clearstatcache()`